# Opacity should only affect parent but no child

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` which contains text on an images, and what I'm trying to achieve is to lower the opacity of the `div` so the images can be seen clearly.

with my current script, when I lower the opacity of the `div` it affects the text too.

but i want it to only affect the div only

### CSS

```
.page1_text {
        position:absolute;
        background-color:#CC3;
        border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
        padding:20px;
        width:80%;
        left:10%;
        font-size:16px;
        opacity: 0.5;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="page1_text">
    <div>This is my test </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use background color instead rgba format, so that you can add opacity and not affect the content https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: where is the image in your HTML markeup? can you create a demo page? i suggest at jsbin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use opacity on the div, it will affect everything in the div

Use background colour with alpha

```
background-color: rgba(204, 204, 51, 0.5);
```

the 0.5 at the end is the alpha(opacity), I got the values using photoshop but I am sure there are other ways to convert hex into rgb

for more info see https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/